# How "max-http-header-size" work with spring?

Tags: java, spring-boot, out-of-memory

I founded an issue "***Request header is too large***" in my system(microservice).

After that I POC and try to understand about How "max-http-header-size" work?

this is information that I test.

I have a request(POST API, request delay 2000ms) and set max-http-header-size in many values.

number of size/number of request success (before 400 "Request header is too large")

max-http-header-size: **2000**/0

max-http-header-size: **2500**/7 (return 400 after success 7 times)

max-http-header-size: **3000**/20 (return 400 after success 20 times)

from this link: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-max-http-header-size
It means the max size of the request header on each request that the server can be allowed.

My question is "max-http-header-size" it doesn't mean max size of request header only? It seems like the size of total request header memory. It can be fully and will return 400 errors.